# How do you add ConfigurationRoot to Dependency Injection in UWP program?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, uwp, configuration

In my UWP application, I'm able to use the **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration** package to read from JSON formatted appSettings files.

```
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{App.UWPENVIRONMENT}.json", true, true)
        .Build();
    string clientId = configuration["security:clientId"];
    string authority = configuration["security:authority"];
```

What I can't seem to be able to do now is make the configuration available to the rest of my UWP application using the **System.Composition** Dependency Injection.  Because of the way the configuration object is built (using the **Build** method), I can't figure out how to embed this configuration in some sort of constructor.

One option that comes to mind is that I could associate an interface with an object, like this:

```
        conventions.ForObject(configuration)
            .Shared()
            .Export(ecb => ecb.AsContractType<IConfiguration>());
```

But the DI package doesn't seem to support this way of thinking.  How do I solve this:

1. Find a way to to build a type.
2. Associate an interface with a concrete instance.
3. Other

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to create a typed ConfigurationRoot:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration for this application.
    /// </summary>
    public class ApplicationConfiguration : ConfigurationRoot
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The client id of the service application to which we want to connect.
        /// </summary>
#if PRODUCTION
        private const string UWPENVIRONMENT = "Production";
#elif STAGING
        private const string UWPENVIRONMENT = "Staging";
#else
        private const string UWPENVIRONMENT = "Development";
#endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationConfiguration"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public ApplicationConfiguration()
            : base(ApplicationConfiguration.GetProviders())
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configuration providers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A list of the configuration providers.</returns>
        private static List<IConfigurationProvider> GetProviders()
        {
            // Build a configuration that reads from the appsettings.json files and extract the providers.
            IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ApplicationConfiguration.UWPENVIRONMENT}.json", true, true)
                .Build();
            return configurationRoot.Providers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And add it to DI:

```
    conventions.ForType<ApplicationConfiguration>().Shared().Export(ecb => ecb.AsContractType<IConfiguration>());
```

Your client will now use configuration files roughly the same way as a .NET Core web service.